# CLion checks and extern declaration of a C++ class without default constructor

Tags: c++, clion, clang-static-analyzer

I have a working class, as example:

```
// MyClass.h

class MyClass {
public:

    explicit MyClass(unsigned char enablePin);

    void enable(bool enable);

private:
    const unsigned char mEnabePin;
};
```

---

```
// MyClass.cpp

#include "MyClass.h"
#include <gpio.h>

MyClass::MyClass(unsigned char enablePin) 
    : mEnabePin(enablePin) {
}

void MyClass::enable(bool enable) {
    gpio_set(mEnabePin, static_cast<unsigned char>(enable ? 0 : 1));
}
```

Then I have in another file `extern` declaration of one instance of this class:

```
// main.h

extern MyClass myClass;
```

and of course an actual definition in one `.cpp` file:

```
// main.cpp
#include "main.h"
#include <Board.h>

MyClass myClass(Board::Pins::MYCLASS_ENABLE_PIN);

int main() {
    // ...
    myClass.enable(true);
}
```

This compiles without warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` and also works well.

However it seems that CLion 2017.2.1 does not properly get the `extern` declaration and always complains about:

[image]

and offers me these intention actions:

[image]

despite the fact that it recognises declaration-definition as it shows red-green arrows as a *Go to definition/declaration* shortcut.

I could turn off this type of checks, but they belong to very useful set of type checks, that is *Function parameter count mismatch* which I do not want to turn off.

[image]

Have anyone run into the same problem and found a neat workaround?

Comment: What are you using for building? `CMake`?

Comment: I use CLion's CMake only for indexing the files (which is also working OK). For building I am using external `make` build system via terminal (via `bash` command in Command Prompt and Windows Linux Subsystem).

Comment: Do you have multiple layer/directory `CMake` for indexing? meaning multiple `CMake` files under sub root directories.

Comment: Yes, my root make in the project includes other `CMakeLists.txt` files from SDKs and frameworks (also via environmental variables).

Comment: If the header included for `MyClass` is not in the top `CMakeLists.txt`, make it so it is part of it and freshen up the indexing.

Comment: I wanted to do that but discovered that this already is the situation (all of my custom files are in the top level `CMake`). I double checked and did *Reset Cache and Reload Project* but it didn't help.